# Error when running function, browser say it loop itself

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have made an Ajax function and when I try to run it, the console returns an error saying (when I check the error on google) that the function try to loop itself.

```
$("#btnRent").click(function () {
    var startDate = $("#txtStartDate");
    var endDate = $("#txtEndDate");
    var url = window.location.href.split('/')[5];

    AddBook(startDate, endDate, url);
});

var AddBook = function (StartTime, EndTime, ProductId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/AddBooking',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: { StartTime: StartTime, EndTime: EndTime, ProductId: ProductId },
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        };
```

Error from Consol log. `too much recursion`

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: why don't you try keeping `ajax` directly in click `event` instead of inside `function`?

Comment: normally i also do that, but this was my last attemp before postiong here. It also return the same error

Comment: if you comment the line `AddBook(startDate, endDate, url);` whether the error is going off

Comment: If i Outcomment `AddBook(startDate, endDate, url);` it dont show the error. But if i debug i never get into my controller because it says it loops

Comment: Try passing values instead of elements like  `var startDate = $("#txtStartDate").val();
    var endDate = $("#txtEndDate").val();`

Answer (score 0):

try replace `location.reload();` with `document.location.reload();`